# PostgreSQL - Intelligently partitioning tables on 'Now()'

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table of data that specifies a time range for each row, that is, each field contains a start_time and end_time field. I would like to be able to partition this table into three tables: historical, current and future, based on the current time. The purpose of this is to increase the performance of select queries on the table, since a large portion of the data is historical, and the majority of queries only need to access current data. I have setup these partitions and they are almost working as I was hoping, except for the fact that data does not transition between the tables with the passage of time. For example, if a row is inserted into the parent table with a start_time greater than the current time, I need that row to move into the 'current' table when 'Now()' >= start_time.

I realise that partitioning on a dynamic value prevents the query engine from optimising the query correctly, but I can easily add in some application logic to hit the correct child table based on a specified date. Is there any way that this functionality can be achieved without too much overhead (not necessarily using partitions)? The data will be batch processed nightly, if that helps at all. Note that the timestamps need to be accurate to the second.

Comment: Perhaps you should just put the data into two separate tables a "historical" and a "future" one.  This is not really a use-case for table partitioning.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The data needs to be capable of transitioning from 'Future' to 'Current' to 'Historical' without direct maintenance

Comment: There's a few alternate approaches, for example: insert to both `historical` and `current` tables simultaneously, but delete old rows regularly from `current`; use materialized views; create tables dynamically with a date suffix, and in code control which table to insert and which to query from. Which is best highly depends on your transaction volume. How many writes? What's the total volume of data and time? What types of queries (reads) are you doing and how frequently -- do reads often involve new and old data? Do queries always have to include absolute latest data (realtime)?

Comment: @gregmac These tables exist as part of a lambda architecture, as such, all writes will go into a real time table and combined with the output of the 'current' table. As such, the number of writes will effectively by 0. The data in the tables has to be real time. The nature of the queries is very basic; typically select * where field='val' type queries.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to have some partitioning that _automatically_ moves rows from a "future" to a "current" to a "past" tables. AFAIK, that's not possible in PostgreSQL (nor in any other common DB I know of). You can use _date_  (or any other time-interval) partitioning to get something similar (Check [Scaling PostgreSQL Performance Using Table Partitioning](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/scaling-postgresql-performance-table-partitioning), for instance)